# Serialize multiple inputs into a single parameter

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following form:

```
<form method="get">
  <input id="search-input" name="search" value="inbox" placeholder="Search ..." type="text">
  <input id="filter-type" name="filter" value="draft" type="text">
  <input id="filter-start-date" name="filter" value="10/10/2020" type="text">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

On submit of the form the generated URL is: `https://example.com/?search=inbox&filter=draft&filter=10%2F10%2F2020`

This results in 1 `search` parameter and 2 `filter` parameters being sent:

```
search=inbox
```

```
filter=draft
```

```
filter=10%2F10%2F2020
```

What I would like to do is send 1 `search` parameter and value, and 1 `filter` parameter with 2 values.

Ideally the url would look like this:

`https://example.com/?search=inbox&filter=draft&10%2F10%2F2020`

The result being 1 `search` parameter, and 1 `filter` parameter with 2 values being sent:

```
search=inbox
```

```
filter=draft&10%2F10%2F2020
```

Can I join these 2 filter input fields into a single query string?

```js
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  var datastring = $("#target").serialize();
  console.log(datastring);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="target" method="get">
  <input id="search-input" name="search" value="inbox" placeholder="Search ..." type="text">
  <input id="filter-type" name="filter" value="draft" type="text">
  <input id="filter-start-date" name="filter" value="10/10/2020" type="text">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: *Ideally the url would look like this* is showing a URL with one filter parameter that has only one value, is that a mistake?

Comment: As for the solution itself, have you considered performing a custom submit function for the form? This will allow you to costomize the paramters then send the user manually to the right address.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Yes my mistake - corrected.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi I was hoping there might be a way to just flatten or merge the 2 values against the filter parameter without writing anything custom

Comment: I understand that, but the problem is, what you want does not represent a valid [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), so you pretty much have to do this manually (i.e. custom).

Comment: Please include the code from the fiddle in the question itself. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to use an interface similar to jsFiddle to do so.

Comment: The easiest solution to your problem would be to rename your filter input to `filter[]`. This way both filter strings will be sent individually, but on the receiving end they will be interpreted as two values for the array `$filter`. This is at least the case for a PHP backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a mistake to send 2 input field values in a query string, but you have to deal with it on the server end. ie, you will will need to know to split the 2 values.

```js
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  var datastring = '?search='+$("#search-input").val()+'&filter='+$("#filter-type").val();
  //datastring = datastring + add a delimiter in here

  datastring = datastring + $("#filter-start-date").val();
  console.log(datastring);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="target" method="get">
  <input id="search-input" name="search" value="inbox" placeholder="Search ..." type="text">
  <input id="filter-type" name="filter" value="draft" type="text">
  <input id="filter-start-date" name="filter" value="10/10/2020" type="text">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```